# Using curves for cursive type

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

This is more of a best practice question. I'm creating some type using curves, and can see there's a couple of ways I could do it. I've used bezier curves to create this, but finding it difficult to make the curves smooth (they just look bumpy) when I'm adding depth.

Question is what the best type of curve and handles to make this smooth and effective? As ever appreciate the advice

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show the parts you're not glad with? Have you tried to increase the resolution of your curve?

Comment: Hey again moonboots. I've attached another screengrab, it's not neccessarily that I'm not happy, it's just that to get a smooth curve I'm looking from every angle and there's always somewhere it doesn't look right. So from the top it looks ok, but generally it's a bit iffy. Just wasn't sure if it's the best type of curve to use. Eg I wasn't sure if a path curve would be better as it doesn't have the handles? But I don't like the offsetting it does when you lay it out

Comment: Those vertices I've added aren't that bad but you see the point I think, it's just not as smooth as I'd like — mainly because of how I'm pulling handles all over the place

Comment: I guess you want to keep it as curve so that you can animate it? Maybe share just a letter so that we can give a try? Maybe try with some tilt or radius changes?

Comment: No problem @moonboots, have added the file. I'm not too worried about keeping it as a curve, once it was drawn I was going to convert to mesh and try to join up the various parts of the frame. Just want to figure out the right way to get the smooth curves. As you turn around the file you'll see it shows that handles go all over the place

Comment: In the Object Data Properties panel >Shape > increase the Resolution, also give it a Subdivision Surface modifier, also as I said you can play with the Radius and Tilt of the vertices (in that case in the Object Data > Active Spline there are some Interpolation Tilt and Radius modes that improve the result), other than that I guess there's no other parameter, it you want to have more freedom you'll need to convert to mesh and move the verticces

Comment: Thanks moonboots I've had a look at those inputs and it is starting to looks a bit smoother. Will continue moving the handles and see where I get to — thanks for looking at this. Just to confirm, do you reckon this is the right sort of curve to use for something like this?

Comment: yes this is the kind of curve you need